# AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: opencv

I am trying to add random noise to images. When I try to print the shape of the image, it seem to print correctly but, there is this error which says "'NoneType' object has no attribue 'shape'"

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04;
Python ver.: 3.7.3;
Opencv ver: 4.1.0

```py
 def rand_noise(image,prob):

    print("Check",image.shape)
    output = np.zeros(image.shape,np.uint8)
    thres = 1 - prob 
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            rdn = random.random()
            if rdn < prob:
                output[i][j] = 0
            elif rdn > thres:
                output[i][j] = 255
            else:
                output[i][j] = image[i][j]
    return output
```

On removing the print function, the same error is shown for the next line.

This is the error message:

```py
Check (720, 1280, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noise&blur.py", line 71, in <module>
    noise_imgR = sp_noise(imageR,0.005)
  File "noise&blur.py", line 11, in sp_noise
    print("Check",image.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: By the way, the path to image is right. Displaying the image (cv2.imshow(image)) was working. And the function "sp_noise()" in the error message was later renamed to  "rand_noise()", the error message being copied before the renaming.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `image` is None when that check is executed. Work backwards from there. E.g., verify that you're callling `rand_noise` with right arguments.